# How are compiler warning and Errors defined and are they ever included in the standard

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, standards

As a folow on the this [question](http://Why%20is%20C4062%20Visual%20C++%20warning%20off%20by%20default?).  Are compiler errors and warnings ever standard specified and if not why not.  I have coded in both gcc and vs for a long time and learning what the warnings and errors are trying to tell you is not a uniform experience.  With languages like .net and java where one entity has overarching control its not as interesting a question. Wouldn't there be some value in standard warning and errors and level categorization.   I'm mostly interested in c++ or C given the number of compilers available for these standards.

Answer (score 3):

It (obviously?) varies from one language to another.

The C standard doesn't require any warnings at all.  It requires a "diagnostic" for any translation unit that violates a constraint or syntax rule, but it doesn't require the translation unit to be rejected.  The only case where a translation unit must be rejected is when it contains a `#error` directive that isn't `#if`'ed out.  C++ rules are similar.  gcc commonly warns about constraint violations, though you can change that with `-pedantic-errors`.

One advantage of this is that it allows a compiler to implement extensions.  If it recognizes `0b11001001` as a binary constant, for example, it can issue a warning for the syntax error and then continue to compile the program.

Ada, on the other hand, requires the compiler to reject source files with errors, and requires compile-time warnings (which do not cause the compilation to fail) for some constructs.

As for a definition, a warning is a diagnostic that doesn't cause the compilation to fail.

It would be useful to define the categorization, but impractical to do so across languages.

Comment: I was asking more in the vain of one compiler of a language compared to another compiler of the same language.  There would be no way to reconcile the different language idioms into a uniform set of errors for all languages.

Comment: Without specifying which language you're interested in, I suspect you question is too broad to get meaningful answers.

Comment: Edited as per your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, language standards define only what a conforming language implementation (e.g. a compiler) does on a conforming program source. They don't define what warnings can be. They do speak of "undefined" or "implementation specific" behavior.

For instance, GCC may give different warnings depending upon its version (4.6 is more precise than 4.5) and upon the requested optimizations.